# JavaFX: How to manage the focus traversal in a borderpane

Tags: java, javafx, focus, keyboard-navigation

I'd like to know if it is possible using TAB or Shift+TAB to navigate in different parts of the Borderpane element?

Comment: what do you mean by `parts of BorderPane` ?

Comment: Sorry, I'd like to say the children of the BorderPane (Top, Left, Center, Right and Bottom).

Comment: Well, you can switch between `Controls` present in the same `Layout`. If you have a `gridpane` in the center of `Borderpane`, which has 4 textfields and a button, you can use TAB to switch `Focus` between them

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like the following:

```
borderPane.getTop().addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.TAB) {
            borderPane.getLeft().requestFocus();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! After analysis, the BorderPane manages correctly the TAB and SHIFT+TAB. But, I had a problem when the previous control is a TabPane. Impossible to move focus to the previous focusable control outside the TabPane. I must implement a workaround to move back focus to the previous control.

Comment: Move focus inside the TabPane has been handled correctly using the 8u20 version.